# Get formatted value from webattribute with typescript xrmquery

Tags: typescript, dynamics-crm, xrm, xrmquery

I have a xrmquery in typescript:

[image]

cgk_employerid_guid is like this:

[image]

I need to get the cgk_employerid_formatted value.
But when the query runs it gives cgk_employerid_guid as a string, so it's not possible to get the formatted value from it.

Does anyone knows the solution to get the formatted value with the select of the query?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a retrieve multiple call in XrmQuery, you can also apply `includeFormattedValues()` on the query, just before executing it.

This will include the formatted values of the retrieved attributes in the result.